# Check if the given function is CDF.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

So, here is the function: $$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$, for $-\infty<x<\infty$. I need to make sure that the given function is PDF. So, I must check whether 
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}dx\stackrel{?}{=}1$$

$$\int \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}dx=\left[ u=1+e^{-x}  \rightarrow du=-e^{-x} \rightarrow dx=-e^x  \right]= \int \frac{1}{(1-u)u}du=\int\frac{1}{u-u^2}du=ln(u)+\frac{1}{u}=ln(1+e^{-x})+\left.\frac{1}{1+e^{-x} }\right|^{\infty}_{-\infty}=lim_{x \to \infty}\left(ln(1+e^{-x})+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \right)-lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(  ln(1+e^{-x})+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}  \right)=1-\infty$$
The result seems to be off. can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: How did you get that $\color{red}{\int \frac{-1}{1+e^u}\, du = -\ln(1+e^u)}$? This is not correct.

Comment: The derivative of $1 + e^u$ is $e^u$, so evaluating the integral as a logarithm is incorrect, since $e^u$ is not on the numerator.

Comment: Also I don't see what do you mean by ensuring that this function is a pdf. It is given to be a cdf. And given the function, even if you make the above changes in evaluating the integral, it will still be unbounded.

Comment: @sudeep5221 now I corrected the question. Yes, I just need to make sure whether the integral is equal to 1 or not, and I thought that my result was incorrect, although it is possible to not have it equal to 1. So, what about the result now?

Comment: @JVV So, now I corrected my solution, but it still looks weird. I expressed $e^{-x}$ as $u-1$ and since I need to express $-e^x$ I rewrote it as $\frac{1}{u-1}$, but am not sure whether that makes any sense. Then in the end I still get indeterminacy.

Comment: This is a sigmoid curve so it is definitely not a PDF (it is not even integrable over $\Bbb R$). It is instead a CDF

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ok, it's true, I had to check whether it's a CDF. But out of curiosity, if it's not integrable, where my integration went wrong?

Comment: @user the mistake is that $$\int \frac{1}{u-u^2}\neq \ln(u)+\frac1u$$ but rather $$\int \frac{1}{u-u^2}=\ln(u)-\ln(u-1)$$ so the indefinite integral of the sigmoid is $$\ln(1+\exp(x))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By showing that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=1$ and $\frac{\partial}{dx}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\geq0$ you can show that the function is a cumulative distribution function (not a pdf)